# How do I calculate the variability in the time taken for a given number of random events of a given frequency to occur?

Tags: poisson-distribution

I'm trying to build a clock in Minecraft that measures approximate time according to random events.  For a deeper explanation as to why I'll make a comment below, but basically I want to make a clock that fires to approximate a given number of minutes by counting the number of sugar cane items that randomly grow from a given number of plants.  It's an unusual problem which I suspect is why answers are difficult to find.

So in my case, sugar cane grows on average every 18 minutes, so if I have 18 plants, I can expect one new growth every minute on average.  If I have 36 plants then I can expect one growth every 30 seconds on average.

So if I have 18 plants then I should should count 100 growth events to approximate 100 minutes passing.  If I have 36 plants I should count 200 events, which should be more accurate.

The question I have is, how accurate can I expect this timer to be?  If it counts 10,000 growths from 1,800 plants then how much more accurate will it be compared to counting 100 growths from 18 plants?  What would be the distribution?

For practical reasons I'm trying to count 167 minutes by observing 32 plants, so I'm counting 1/18 * 32 * 167 ~= 297 (rounded) growth events, but I'd like to know the general method for any number of plants and amount of time.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't have the right tags or terms in my post, I really don't know the correct terminology, which is another reason why this question is hard to research.  I've found this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352421/confidence-interval-for-event-rate  It's not a duplicate though, because it's the inverse problem:  how confident can you be about the true rate of events given observations, but I'm asking about how confident I can be about the observations I'll get given a known rate.

Comment: Why I'm doing this: I need to measure the time that has elapsed for a given region in terms of random block ticks, which govern growth of plants and other things in the game.  I know the time I need to measure, 167 minutes, but the standard method of measuring time is with a redstone clock.  However sometimes the game processes redstone without processing growth, and I need to be able to distinguish the two, and the only way to do that is to monitor a known random process.  The other random process I'm manipulating with this clock can't be directly measured, so I'm doing it this way.